# How to manually dispatch hashchange event

Tags: javascript

1 - What is correct syntax for WebKit (primary for Safari on iPad, good if it works on Win Chrome) to `.addEventListener` to `hashChange` event?

2 - Is is possible (and how) to manually/programmatically dispatch hashChange event by `.dispatchEvent` on browsers mentioned above?

TIA.

I've found answer for 1:

`window.addEventListener("hashchange", function() {console.log(location.hash)});`

But I still have no idea how to dispatch `hashchange` manual since I don't know what `EVENTOBJECT` I should pass to `window.dispatchEvent(EVENTOBJECT)`.

Comment: I have asked this question after few attempts to get it working so I assumed that I lack some basic part of knowledge about this process.  And that is why I'm asking for basics. You don't have any proof for my lack of effort. But if you still can help me with that i will be very grateful.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you want to force hashchcange event without literaly changing hash you should call:

```
window.dispatchEvent(new HashChangeEvent("hashchange"))
```

Object passed to the event handler will have this props available:

```
String oldURL;
String newURL;
```

This is an only info I found about this:

[https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/Source/WebCore/dom/HashChangeEvent.h](http://forum.php.pl/index.php?showtopic=213470)

after receiving answer here:

[http://forum.php.pl/index.php?showtopic=213470](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/Source/WebCore/dom/HashChangeEvent.h)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to make it work on Internet Explorer (IE11) too

```js
/**
 * cross browser hash change event dispatch
 */
function dispatchHashchange() {
    if (typeof HashChangeEvent !== "undefined") {
        window.dispatchEvent(new HashChangeEvent("hashchange"));
        return;
    }

    // HashChangeEvent is not available on all browsers. Use the plain Event.
    try {
        window.dispatchEvent(new Event("hashchange"));
        return;
    } catch (error) {
        // but that fails on ie
    }

    // IE workaround
    const ieEvent = document.createEvent("Event");
    ieEvent.initEvent("hashchange", true, true);
    window.dispatchEvent(ieEvent);
}
```