# Is there a way to fire a 'hashchange' event even if the hash is the same?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, typescript

I have an event listener like this:

```
window.addEventListener('hashchange', () => setTimeout(() => this.handleHashChange(), 0));
```

Then in this `handleHashChange` function I have some logic for scrolling to an on page element. Taking into account the space it needs to leave for the collapsing/expanding header.
If I go to `#team` from `#mission` this works fine. The problem is when I click `#team` twice. Since the hash stays the same it doesn't go in the event listener and falls back to the default browser scroll. I then end up with my header on top of the element, not leaving enough space. 
Is there a way to overwrite that, too?

Can be jquery or vanilla JS

Comment: If the hash is the same then it’s not a hash change even to begin with. Feels like an XY problem you’re running into.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to force hashchcange event without literaly changing hash you should call: 
    `window.dispatchEvent(new HashChangeEvent("hashchange"))`

[Related question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15035217/how-to-manually-dispatch-hashchange-event)