# How to trigger an event whenever the user enters a url with a fragment although the same url is loaded already?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple website in HTML where there are several sections tagged with ids, so it is possible to jump directly to the specified section with URI fragments (e.g. https://example.org/index.php#header1). I use JavaScript to scroll a bit further when the `hashchange` event is triggered. However, if the user already is on e.g. https://example.org/index.php#header1, scrolls around and then presses enter in the URL bar, the browser will jump to the specified section but the event will not be triggered as the fragment did not actually change. Is there any way I can still make my event trigger?

Comment: You can try [dispatching a hashchange event when page loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15035217/how-to-manually-dispatch-hashchange-event)

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for the answer! I tried that solution but the problem is that the browser (tested on Firefox and Safari) actually doesn't reload the page if the fragment didn't change even though the user presses enter, therefore no event will be triggered

Comment: "the browser will jump to the specified section" that's actually against the specs since [last week](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/7386) :P. Now setting the hash to the same value should not do anything, and thus I guess Chrome's behavior of reloading the page when pressing enter makes sense since resetting the full href does reload the page. So my guess is that Firefox will soon enough follow Chrome's behavior here.

Comment: "I use JavaScript to scroll a bit further when the hashchange event is triggered." Can't you use CSS to achieve this? For instance you can trick the position of your target elements with a pseudo element: https://jsfiddle.net/jfqcL9dw/

Comment: @Kaiido That's somewhat good news at least, thank you! I can confirm that it works in Chrome as I intended, let's hope other browser engines pick the new specs up quickly ;). Pure CSS is unfortunately not a solution for me, as I actually do a bit more than just scrolling with the JavaScript (I also add a class to that item and make minor page changes based on the fragment).

Comment: Since I'm apparently not doing anything wrong since the specs have been updated, I'm fine with not having a workaround for the moment. Thank you all for your help! If anyone does have a workaround, I'm of course still very open to suggestions ;)